# Counting the total amount of rows which bear negative values with corresponding row

Tags: excel

I am in need of a formula, which counts the sums of two rows for a whole column.

e.g.

I have data in column A and column B and would like to make a count of the sums for A1+B1, A2+B2, etc.. for around 1800 rows. If one of the columns is empty, it should not be included in the count.

This is to find out how many negatives I have in my column when adding A1 + B1, A2+ B2 and so on...

I try to explain it in the link to the picture.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlZPa.png

Basically I could do it with an extra column but since I have 50+ customers I would have to add a column for each to make the diff, so I was hoping to express the Yellow column in a formula so I only have to adapt that instead of insert a calculation column for each column.

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the rows based on some values to get all rows containing negative value if this is what you wish to achieve.

follow these steps:

- Select The column that contains negative values.
- click on the "Data" tab.
- Click "Filter" or Cntrl+Shift+L.
- Click the black arrow pointing down on top of the column you have selected.
- Select "Number Filters"
- Click "Less Than"
- Type 0 (zero) and hit Enter.
  you should have only the cells containing negative values displayed.

If you need to get the total rows containing positive values in a column, use this formula
=MIN(COUNTIF(A:A,">0")) where column is "A"

To get the total of negative cells in a row, you can use
=MIN(COUNTIF(A:A,"<0")) where column is "A"

Comment: hey, not quite what I was looking for. the data tab and the filter option are not very usefull as the file gets constantly updated (new rows being added), also it is quite manual. I added a link to a picture, maybe that makes it clearer.